# Mostar datos Binding WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Buen día, 
He tenido problemas para mostrar los datos en un grid usando wpf el código no me arroja error y revisando el paso a paso veo que los métodos si toman los valores registrados en la DB pero no los lleva al grid.
Comparto código:

**1.Vista**

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inspección #" Binding="{Binding Path=numeroInspeccion}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vehiculo" Binding="{Binding Path=vehiculo}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Conductor" Binding="{Binding Path=conductor}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha" Binding="{Binding Path=fecha}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inspector" Binding="{Binding Path=inspector}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**2.Modelo**

```
public DataTable CargarInspeccion()
        {


 DataTable dt = new DataTable("CargarInspeccion");
        SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();

        try
        {
            SqlCon.ConnectionString = Conexion.Cn;
            //SqlCon.Open();

            //Código con sentencia
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "PRC_CARGAR_INSPECCION";
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter SqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            SqlDat.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            dt = null;
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

**3.Vista Modelo**

```
private void CargarDatosInspeccion()
    {
        List<EstructuraDtg> obj = new List<EstructuraDtg>();

        foreach(DataRow dr in Operaciones.CargarInspecciones().Rows)
        {
            obj.Add(new EstructuraDtg { NumeroInspeccion = dr[0].ToString(), Vehiculo = dr[1].ToString(), Conductor = dr[2].ToString(), Fecha = dr[3].ToString(), Inspector = dr[4].ToString() });
        }

        this.DtInspeccion.ItemsSource = obj;
}
```

Comment: Que tipo de dato es `obj`?

Comment: @Einer hola, en obj guardo todos los valores que recojo en cada uno de los item del foreach

Comment: Noto que en los bindings tienes las propiedades en minusculas pero en el objeto son Captalized por lo que no son iguales

Comment: Reemplaza `{Binding Path=numeroInspeccion}` por `{Binding Path=NumeroInspeccion}` y dime que pasa.

Comment: Probablemente este recibien errores en la consola al hacer los binding. Pero como no cortan el programa no se haya dado cuenta. Fijate que en la consola salen los errores de binding.

Comment: Me funciono!! mil gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En los bindings tienes las propiedades en minusculas pero en el objeto son Captalized por lo que no son iguales.

Reemplaza

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inspección #" Binding="{Binding Path=numeroInspeccion}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vehiculo" Binding="{Binding Path=vehiculo}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Conductor" Binding="{Binding Path=conductor}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha" Binding="{Binding Path=fecha}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inspector" Binding="{Binding Path=inspector}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
```

Por:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inspección #" Binding="{Binding Path=NumeroInspeccion}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vehiculo" Binding="{Binding Path=Vehiculo}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Conductor" Binding="{Binding Path=Conductor}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha" Binding="{Binding Path=Fecha}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inspector" Binding="{Binding Path=Inspector}" Visibility="Visible" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
```